# jQuery radio fustrations: .change is not working as expected in Firefox 3.6.13

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onchange

I have searched on Google, jQuery, and stackoverflow for this issue and all basically give the same examples.

I followed the radio `.change()` examples explained, but I could not get it to work.  My code is straightforward. The user must click either male or female.  On change, the `.change()` is supposed to fire the alert(for test purposes) and the function.  However, neither are firing.  Both my jQuery and HTML code "look" correct, but I am not exactly sure why it is not firing.

HTML code:

```
<div class="float_right">
    <label for="gender">*Gender:</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
    <div id="gender_error">
        <ul class="ul">
            <li class="gender_error_1 element_error">Choose either male or female!</li>
            <li class="element_valid">a</li>
        </ul>                               
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function)(){
    alert('Gender has changed!');
    validateElement('#add_livestock', 'gender', '.gender_error_1')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function)(){
```

it should be

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function(){
```

Comment: I knew it was simple; it is late and I am sleepy.  Thank You for helping me with the fix.

Comment: I knew it was simple; it is late and I am sleepy.  Thank You for helping me with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo - an extra parentheses:

Change

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function)(){
```

to:

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function(){
```

[JSFiddle with fixed code](http://jsfiddle.net/NqCBQ/)

Answer (score 1):

You jQuery code is wrong:

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function)(){
```

*should be*

```
$("input[name='gender']").change(function(){
```

have a close look to the parentheses.